# What does Next dimension means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading Casper (1995) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_(film)) article, I came across the word "**Next dimension**" in this sentence.

> Kat Harvey's father who is a ghost therapist interacting with the
>   living impaired to cross into the **next dimension** while hoping to find
>   his deceased wife.

Comment: BTW, you can be "*too* impaired to do something", but "impaired to do something" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the afterlife, or heaven, or whatever you want to call it.  "The next dimension" is just a term that doesn't carry the deep religious connotations that using a term like "heaven" would.

Basically it means he wants to help the ghosts move on to wherever they go after they stop remaining on Earth.